# angularjs modal view not showing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to show a confirmation modal in angular js but i'm not getting the result needed:

here is my code :

```
$scope.deleteModal = function(item_id) {
     var post = list_item.getItem(item_id).then(function(item){
        $scope.item = item;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: '../popup/delete.html',
              controller: $scope.modal,
              size: 'sm',
              resolve: {
                item: function () {
                  return $scope.item;

                }
              }
            });
        },function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        })
    };

$scope.modal = function($scope, $modalInstance, item) {
```

I'm getting my view but not i a modal 
[image]

here is my modal template :

```
<div>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4>@lang('messages.popup_delete')</h4>
</div>  

    <div class="modal-body">
       <p>@lang('messages.popup_del_q')  ?</p>
    </div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <table>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:30px;"></td>
               <td style="width:120px;"><button   class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(item.id)" >@lang('messages.confirm')</button></td>
               <td style="width:20px;"></td>
               <td><button   class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()" >@lang('messages.cancel')</button></td>
           </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you must have missed to add css file of `angular-ui-bootstrap`

Comment: ive added it var study = angular.module('study', ['ngRoute' , 'ui.bootstrap' ]

Comment: did you confirmed that css file of ui-bootstrap has there in your project or not?

Comment: yes it's there i don't know what im missing

Comment: could you reproduce it in plunkr please'

Comment: I think it's just your template.  From the picture, it looks like the modal is working (I see buttons, backdrop and message).  Seems like you're missing the modal content/modal-header/modal-body/modal-footer classes in the template.  Can you please post your custom template and any corresponding custom css?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing a closing `</div>` tag in the end of your template. (or just remove the first opening `<div>` tag).